# Как добавить блок добавления комментариев на сайт?

Tags: php, html, css, комментарии

Объясните, пожалуйста, что писать в css, php, html файлах? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Двигаемся по упрощенной схеме. Во-первых, база, три таблицы.

Первая (messages), где хранятся сообщения/товары/новости: `id(auto_increment), text`

Вторая (comments), где хранятся непосредственно комментарии: `id(auto_increment), msg_id, text, user_id`

Третья (users), где хранятся пользователи: `id(auto_increment), name, login, password`

HTML вывод:

```
//выбираем из базы все сообщения, запросом типа: select * from messages
//выводим в цикле сообщения
<div class="message_body">
тело сообщения
//выбираем из базы комментарии в соответствии с текущей новостью.
//запрос типа select c.text as text, u.name as user_name from users u,comments c where c.msg_id = 'id сообщения' and u.id=c.user_id
//выводим комментарии в цикле 
   <div class="comment_body">
    текст и имя пользователя
   </div>
//здесь форма добавления нового комента, что то типа:
<div class="comment_add">

<form>
<input type="hidden" value="id новости" name="msg_id">
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="добавить комментарий">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Обработчик нового комментария php:

Проверяем, авторизирован ли пользователь; если да, получаем его id, проверяем на валидность пришедшую с сайта информацию, добавляем новый комментарий в базу. user_id у нас есть mgs_id прилетело post'oм, text тоже, id само назначится.

CSS:

А здесь как сердце подскажет. Делаем красивости, извращаемся по полной.

Comment: Перепутал названия таблиц.

Answer (score 1):

Почти ничего, если использовать [этот](http://disqus.com/) инструмент.

Comment: Про это я знаю.. Но мне желательно чтобы все хранилось на моем сайте!

Comment: Тогда отвечу на ваш вопрос так: в css-, html-, php-файлах нужно писать, соответственно, css-, html-, php-код. Очень посоветую вам ещё создать таблицу comments в базе данных.

Проект настолько серьёзный, что вы не доверяете disqus'у? Что ж, значит у вас найдётся пол сотни баксов, чтобы найти фрилансера, который напишет вам блок комментариев.